# Share link for vk.com

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

[ВКонтакте](http://vk.com) is a Facebook clone that is very popular in the Russian Federation. Would it be possible to implement a share link for it along Twitter and Facebook? It would likely produce quite a bit of traffic if used.

Here's the URL

```
http://vk.com/share.php?url=http://russian.stackexchange.com
```

Comment: Good point. Totally agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're currently moving away from providing social media sharing icons at all. In fact, they've all been recently disabled across the entire Stack Exchange network.

If we restore them in the future, we might revisit this, but for now there are no plans to do so.

Comment: Ah, I see. Is there a blog post or something that explains the reasons for this decision?

Comment: @kotekzot There is no blog post, but the gist of the reasoning was "nobody uses these buttons anyway". They saw very minor use across the network and when we tried to make them show up all the time (instead of at random), they just [annoyed people](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136720/but-i-dont-wanna-share).

Comment: Fair enough, I never used them myself but always assumed somebody did, seeing how they are all over the Internet.